# ios find out the button from which the event was raised

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have been looking for a solution, but i cant seem to find it. I have two buttons on the interface. Both call the same action. Is there a way to  find out which button raised the event? i m very new to iphone dev, so please just give me some guidance even if it looks too trivial.

Regards

khizar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In every event you have (id)sender parameter which is the object which triggered event. You can compare it to one of your buttons like this:

```
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {
    if ((UIButton *)sender == myButton1) {
        // you have clicked button 1
    }
}
```

You could also set `tag` property of your buttons, and check this parameter in click function:

```
myButton1.tag = 1;
myButton2.tag = 2;
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {
    if ([[sender] tag] == 1) {
        // you have clicked button 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your method would be `-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender`, where sender is the button that was clicked. Cast it to `UIButton` & off you go! To recognize which button it was, set the tag property when you create the buttons & check the tag in this method.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your two buttons declared in your .h file and then in your method you can do the following by casting the sender to a UIButton. Because we work with pointers we can check the memory address to know what the sending button was. This is out of the top of my head. Might not even be necessary to cast sender...

.h file

```
UIButton* button1;
UIButton* button2;
```

.m file

```
-(void) someMethod:(id)sender
{
    if((UIButton*)sender == button1)
    {
         //code for button1
    }
    else if((UIButton*)sender == button2)
    {
         //code for button2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign unique tag to each button. Let's assume you have two buttons(Button1 and Button2). You can assign tag through storyboard or in your code by doing the following.

```
button1.tag =1;
button2.tag =2;
```

Now, in your action method, you can check if the sender is a button, and if it is, then take a temporary button and set it as the sender. Off course, you have to cast the sender as a UIButton. Now, you can check, which button is clicked. Sample code-

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{

if([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
    UIButton *tempButton = (UIButton*)sender;

    if(tempButton.tag == 1){
        NSLog(@"Button1 is clicked");
    }
    else if(tempButton.tag == 2){
        NSLog(@"Button2 is clicked");
    }
  }
}
```